# Setting frame icon

Tags: java, icons

Okay, so after everything i finally have the base of my game up and running! the only thing is the default window icon is the lwjgl logo :L can someone please tell me how to change this to my custom icon?

Comment: Which toolkit are you using? Awt, Swt, Swing?

Answer (score 1):

For a `JFrame`, use `setIconImage(Image image)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        /* Display the Application Icon */
        BufferedImage images = null;
        try {
            images = ImageIO.read(mainFrame.getClass().getResource("/sample/resources/icon.gif"));
        } catch (IOException es) {
            es.printStackTrace();
        }
        mainFrame.setIconImage(images);
```

Comment: The format shouldn't matter, as for the size I usually make my icons 16 x 16 pixel

Comment: *"The format shouldn't matter"*  Yes it will.  Try setting a TIFF as an icon in the standard JRE.  Rely on PNG, GIF, JPEG, but for the full range available to a JRE, see [`ImageIO.#getReaderFormatNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFormatNames%28%29) & related methods.

Comment: *"does it need to be in a specific .. size?"*  If you supply a group of square icons, the JRE will use whichever one is best suited to the display purpose.  E.G.  [FileBro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110) has 2 icons.  Windows will use the smaller one for the frame icon, and the large one as te icon to show when alt+tab is pressed.